# How to make a REPL?

Tags: java, scala, read-eval-print-loop, anonymous-class

I am working on the REPL for a custom programming language on the JVM. The REPL currently has the ability to read a line and convert it to an AST, using the exact same parsers and AST structures as the compiler. This means that I can convert a line of code in the REPL to an AST representation as if it were a line of code in a `main` method. The problem with this is that I get the AST of a computation, but not its result (obviously), since this requires the actual evaluation of the AST. For this, I have thought of two ways:

1. Computation inside the AST. Fairly straight-forward. Every AST node has to have some sort of `eval` method that folds the AST until only one value is left. Operators can be done by the compiler, methods would be inlined. Problem: Overhead and a lot of `eval` implementations.
2. Computation with Bytecode. Convert the AST to bytecode inside a temporary class, like this:

   ```
   class REPL$1
   {
        public static [insert type] res1;

        static
        {
            res1 = [insert REPL input]
        }
   }
   ```

The problem with this is the fact that for every input line (or result), I would need a separate class. Since results are available during the entire runtime of the REPL, the classes need to stay loaded, and `Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass` cannot be used. After a while, these classes would pile up and cause an `OutOfMemory: Permgen` error.

Which of the two methods is better for REPLs, and how do other REPLs on the JVM (mainly `scala`) solve this issue?

Comment: Use a temporary class loader for each temporary class.

Comment: It's a REPL right? So it's probably going to be used for a very short amount of time. Have you tried option 2 to find out when you run out of memory? Is that after 100 classes or after 100.000? Maybe running out of permgen is more a theoretical problem than an actual one.

Comment: I just implemented my REPL using Option 2, and made it so that expressions that return a value are evaluated with actual classes that stay loaded and `void` expressions / statements are evaluated with anonymous classes. Although it is *a bit* slow at times, it seems to work flawlessly (apart from the billions of errors caused by the compiler code). While I think that it is true that this would probably never happen in the lifetime of the program, I was more interested in the theory of REPLs and wanted to know how other languages do it.